# Layout - Images are not at the bottom and overlap

Tags: java, android, android-layout

As the thread name says, I am facing a problem with overlapping elements. I need to make something like footer, which would always be at the bottom of layout and would not overlap elements. I'm posting my layout below. I believe that the problem is how I position ratings bar and the linear layout, which is supposed to be at the bottom.

P.S Don't blame me for the way I use a relative layout, the slider should have a parent Relative layout and ScrollView can be used only for one general Layout...

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="@drawable/background">

<!--android:margin="5dp"-->

<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:background="#4D000000"
    tools:context="com.daimajia.slider.demo.MainActivity">

    <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        custom:pager_animation="Default"
        custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
        custom:pager_animation_span="1100"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
        android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        custom:selected_color="#0095BF"
        custom:unselected_color="#55333333"
        custom:shape="oval"
        custom:selected_padding_left="5dp"
        custom:selected_padding_right="5dp"
        custom:unselected_padding_left="5dp"
        custom:unselected_padding_right="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        custom:selected_width="6dp"
        custom:selected_height="6dp"
        custom:unselected_width="6dp"
        custom:unselected_height="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
        android:id="@+id/custom_indicator2"
        style="@style/AndroidImageSlider_Corner_Oval_Orange"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Konstitucijos pr. 7A, Vilnius"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pin"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pin"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#433b39"
        android:layout_below="@id/address"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/work_hours"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider1"
        android:text="I - VI 10:00 - 21:00, VII 10:00 - 20:00"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#433b39"
        android:layout_below="@id/work_hours"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <fragment
            android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
            android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#575350"
        android:layout_below="@id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="1.0"
            android:rating="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rating_text"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#575350"
        android:layout_below="@id/rl" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:clickable="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/phone" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mail" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The desired result:
[image]
How it actually looks like:
[image]

Comment: use android:layout_below="id" for last LinearLayout

Comment: Simple way you have to create RelativeLayout Inside two RelativeLayout .Second Layout apply below to first layout .In FirstLayout adding slider and textview and second layout adding Two Image button.. If Require seprator between two layout then adding Seprator-firstrelativelayout-seprator-secondrelativelayout .I think help this way

Answer (score 1):

Add below properties to bottom LinearLayout ;

```
android:layout_below="@id/divider4"
```

**Updated your code :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.daimajia.slider.demo.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background">

        <!--android:margin="5dp"-->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
            android:background="#4D000000">

            <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                custom:pager_animation="Default"
                custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
                custom:pager_animation_span="1100"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Konstitucijos pr. 7A, Vilnius"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_below="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/pin"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/pin"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#433b39"
                android:layout_below="@id/address"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/work_hours"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/divider1"
                android:text="I - VI 10:00 - 21:00, VII 10:00 - 20:00"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#433b39"
                android:layout_below="@id/work_hours"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/divider2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
                android:layout_below="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <fragment
                    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
                    android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#575350"
                android:layout_below="@id/frame_layout"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_below="@+id/divider3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/rl"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:stepSize="1.0"
                    android:rating="0" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/rating_text"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/ratingBar"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#575350"
                android:layout_below="@id/rl" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_below="@id/divider4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:clickable="true">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/number"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/phone" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/mail" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
        android:id="@+id/custom_indicator2"
        style="@style/AndroidImageSlider_Corner_Oval_Orange"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
        android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        custom:selected_color="#0095BF"
        custom:unselected_color="#55333333"
        custom:shape="oval"
        custom:selected_padding_left="5dp"
        custom:selected_padding_right="5dp"
        custom:unselected_padding_left="5dp"
        custom:unselected_padding_right="5dp"
        custom:selected_width="6dp"
        custom:selected_height="6dp"
        custom:unselected_width="6dp"
        custom:unselected_height="6dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well, I'm glad you tried to help me, but, still, it doesn't work. My full layout code just for clarification, if I got your ideas right: http://pastebin.com/iqvCAyNy

Answer (score 0):

use`android:layout_below="id of the devider "`  as i don't know which divider it is

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
android:layout_below="@id/divider4"
```

For last `LinearLayout`